# Single variable logistic regression

Tags: newton-raphson, logistic-regression

I am trying to write out the code for using Newton-Raphson to solve for a coefficient and intercept in a single variable logistic regression.

However in both the math and in the code I see that the Hessian matrix is not invertible. Is Newton-Raphson not applicable to single variable logistic regression or am I just doing something wrong?

If it is not applicable is there anything that converges faster than GD/SGD that I can use? An external library does not fit the use case.

Comment: Write down the math, to determine if the Hessian is indeed not invertible.

Comment: I did, as far as I can tell it is not. The determinant is 0 in the univariate case.

Comment: I meant "write it down *in the question* "